# Changing global variable in Polymer

Tags: web, components, polymer

I've got a component called app-globals which for the moment only has javascript with a variable in it. When clicking a button I want to not only change the variable value, but bind that value to a number of places throughout the app.
I can't find any documentation for this.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That question is already answered here:
[Polymer global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867741/polymer-global-variables)

In short, use objects to store globals:

> "**By using an object with data properties**, as in the edited version
>   above, and only ever reading from and assigning to the data properties
>   of that object rather than overwriting the object itself, **changed
>   values are shareable between instances**."