# Polymer register all elements after my custom function

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have  js file with this

```
var global_actions ={};
$(document).ready(function () {

   myajaxcall(function(response){global_actions=response});

});
```

I have an elements with template :

```
 <template>
 ...
<h1>{{global_actions.greetingtext}}</h1>
...
</template>
```

The problem is that template draw and init before global_actions=myajaxresponse;
What do i want 
1.Call ajax and fill global_actions
2.Draw elements with databinding to global_actions data;
What i got elements draw before myahaxcall(callback);

Comment: your question is not clear.what do you mean with init?

Comment: So put this in template if..
I dont understand why you cant in the ajax change the value of this.myproperty??

Comment: because i have 10 elements and i will not call the same function on all elements. i have one function that fill data for all elements in one global object. after its filled all elements read this object in ELEMENT.ready function.

Comment: sorry, but I dont understand your question, if you want to insert the element after the ajax you can use the template-if , or you can let the binding system work, and show your content after you receive the ajax response.

Comment: Thanks #Alon
i found a solution Global variables :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867741/polymer-global-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all For ajax you can use the ajax component
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax

Second
let say you use dom-bind and the custom element that you want to put is on the main

```
 var global_actions ={};
 $(document).ready(function () {
     myajaxcall(function(response){
     //use app or this
     app.isFinish = true; 
     app.response});
 });
```

in the html write

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[isFinish]]">
   <custom-element some-data={{app.greetingtext}}></custom-element>
</template>
```

thus your element only render when you receive the response from server.