# Use a global variable in Polymer dom-if

Tags: polymer, global-variables, dom-if

I am creating a custom module for Polymer. I need to create a global variable that can be accessed when defining a template. Something like:

`<template is="dom-if" if="[[_check(myGlobalVar.foo)]]">`

The global variable should also be directly accessible from inside the module (see _anotherFunction) . The JS file looks like:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-module',

    _check(f) {
        return f == 'foobar'
    },

    _anotherFunction() {
        console.log(myGlobalVar)
    }
})
```

In addition, myGlobalVar should be accessible from other modules in other files. What's the best way to create it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in two ways.

1. Have a component that can hold all the global variables and gives the same instance of its data where ever it is used. You can find the better explanation using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867741/polymer-global-variables/24876397) along with working sample
2. If you have lot of data that needs to be accessible globally then the best option would be using store with polymer-redux.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific Polymer element for this.

> iron-meta is a generic element you can use for sharing information
>   across the DOM tree.

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-meta

The element fires `value-changed` if a value has been changed, so you probably need to set up values for it.

---

We don't use it in our company however, but just storing the value in memory, and then send an event whenever we set the value. Also adding a listener for every element that needs to listen to updates.